# WordPress: removing google-maps and all those assets completely

Tags: php, wordpress

running the wp-jobmanager and the  theme Jobify: https://astoundify.com/products/jobify/

this includes some google-maps that means it fetches the maps from google-Api.
This may cause some GDPR issues for lots of user in the world. i have tried out some methods and ways.

what is aimed: we tried to find a solution that takes away the google-assets from the page - completly!!

i tried out this solution at the last weekend.

a.Go to the WordPress dashboard and navigate to the "Appearance" section.
b. Click on "Editor" to access the theme files.

c.  Open the "functions.php" file.
Locate the code that initializes the Google Maps API. It should look something like this:

```
function jobify_google_maps_api() {
wp_register_script( 'google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY', array(), null, false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jobify_google_maps_api' );
```

d. Comment out or delete this code to disable the Google Maps API.
Save the changes to the file.

This should remove Google Maps from the Jobify theme completely.

However; using this method we have to keep in mind that removing this functionality may affect other parts of the theme, so we may need to make additional changes or modifications to ensure the theme still works as intended.

**Question** - how to make sure that i can use this method - and be able to do

a. changes
b. modifications
c. updates to the theme

Comment: Create a child theme.

Comment: https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwij4vbhxPWBAxUa13cKHaFsCAQYABAAGgJlZg&ae=2&gclid=CjwKCAjw-KipBhBtEiwAWjgwrNetpGyls9Z5pD3qagBtrqYcUBO3Z487RQ95U9FyT1jvlf0fzMnOmRoCpxQQAvD_BwE&ohost=www.google.nl&cid=CAESVeD2l9iUrPmv7PQ3zUDBe4sNgdCCaZkfN7t9t7Z439RLDyjo1ixbpaeAXeRG5ijSQByOsQ6khW64Fc-vlJrkQwTvkpWpQDizMM0AfI8r6VlZrPmCFwA&sig=AOD64_1uyvCT-4zUdHDiaVzRiCEzN4DO1w&q&adurl&ved=2ahUKEwjj8-7hxPWBAxUx_rsIHehFDGcQ0Qx6BAgHEAE

Comment: hello - it would be awesome if you can provide some more infos., i still struggle with the issue: any help would be greatly appreciatded: https://sicher3.de/webscanner/r/c1bd8866-ccde-4016-a7e1-0d15c5b733d6/

Comment: i would add a bounty - of course.. - if you can help me here on the page : https://www.job-starter.com/